explode and transform concatenated string in rows to columns
I'm a newbie to python and have been struggling with data transformation.
I've a dataframe with data as below.
UserId  PurchaseCnt
u1      Bread:6, Milk:11
u2      Water:3

I want to translate this into a dataframe as follows. How would I do that?
UserId Bread Milk Water
u1     6     11
u2     0     0    3

I need to do this for a large amount of data. Therefore need a decent efficient code.
What is a python code to do this?

Similar: Split / Explode a column of dictionaries into separate columns with pandas

What do you need help with exactly? Like, what have you tried, and where are you stuck? For example, do you know how to do string operations on a df?

Why does Water have a blank while Bread and Milk have 0s? If that's just a typo, please [edit] to fix it.

Code
import re
pat = r'(\w+):(\d+)'
s = df['PurchaseCnt'].map(lambda x: dict(re.findall(pat, x)))
out = df[['UserId']].join(pd.json_normalize(s).astype('float'))

out:
    UserId  Bread   Milk    Water
0   u1      6.0     11.0    NaN
1   u2      NaN     NaN     3.0

Example Code
import pandas as pd
data = {
    'UserId': ['u1', 'u2'],
    'PurchaseCnt': ['Bread:6, Milk:11', 'Water:3']
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)


IIUC, extractall to separate the item name and number, then pivot. Optionally fillna with zeros:
out = (df.drop(columns='PurchaseCnt')
         .join(df['PurchaseCnt']
 .str.extractall(r'(?P<col>\w+):(\d+)')
 .droplevel('match').astype({1: 'Int64'})
 .pivot(columns='col', values=1)
 .fillna(0)
 )
)

Output:
 UserId  Bread  Milk  Water
0     u1      6    11      0
1     u2      0     0      3

